What is the difference between a "sexual disorder" and a "sexual dysfunction"?
https://bestpractice.bmj.com/topics/en-gb/352
https://www.bmj.com/specialties/sexual-and-gender-disorders
What is the distinction between a sexual disorder and a sexual dysfunction?
Why is "hypoactive sexual desire disorder" a disorder according to ICD-10? Why is "sexual anhedonia" a dysfunction according to the ICD-11?
https://icd.who.int/browse/2024-01/mms/en#160690465%2Fother

The sources you present seem to use them as synonyms. Are there reasons (besides the existence of separate words) that you think they should be different or are used differently?

Well
I just wanted to understand the thought process behind referring to one or other?
https://icd.who.int/browse/2024-01/mms/en#1189253773
https://icd.who.int/browse10/2019/en#/F52.0
It seems strange to have two words that mean the same thing, but to switch from one to the other in official documentation without a strong justification?

Not too unusual in English, English writers are often encouraged to use varied language to keep their writing "interesting". "Disorder" fits a bit better when describing a named category; "dysfunction" is more like describing a symptom, but using articles and other modifications you can make either work. Like your car might have "braking dysfunction" meaning the brakes aren't working well, and if enough people have a similar dysfunction we might call it "Hydraulic brake disorder", but Hydraulic brake disorder is still an example of dysfunctional brakes.

The other context around the words is more important than the choice of a particular word.
